# Can you start a question using 'Meanwhile'?

Tags: word-usage

When writing an email I started off with this sentence but now I am having doubts on using 'Meanwhile' at the beginning of a question.

> Meanwhile my absence, did you receive an answer to your mail by one of my colleagues?

I am aware that I could change it but I just wanted to know if the sentence is correct or if it's just a side effect of having to use multiple languages a day?

Comment: To the question in the title: yes, you can. Meanwhile, you might like to add “, in” before “my absence”.

Comment: Meanwhile does not take an object.

Comment: 'Meanwhile, what is our best course of action?' = 'What is our best course of action in the meantime?' (A sitrep is needed in prior context, with a hoped-for solution ... a future vaccine, say.)

Comment: You can start a sentence with _meanwhile_ but what you can't do is to start a conversation with it as it needs a previously established time frame to make any sense. For example if an author started a chapter with "Meanwhile back at headquarters..." there would have to be a previous chapter, or at least a prologue, which described what was happening out in the field. A Surrealist or comic author could do it but that would not be normal usage. What 'meanwhile' doesn't do is replace 'during' as you have tried to make it do.

Answer (score 1):

*Meanwhile* may be used to start a sentence, but not in the way you have attempted.

“I was absent with illness. Meanwhile, my colleagues dealt with my emails”. *Meanwhile* here refers to the period during which I was ill.

Meanwhile =

> until something expected happens, or while something else is happening:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meanwhile)

*Meanwhile* has the connotation that something else is, was, or will be happening; *during* does not.

You have used the word as if it were synonymous with *during*; this is incorrect usage.

> During =
>
> at some time between the beginning and the end of a period:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/during)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile is an adverb. Like all adverbs it can start a sentence:

Meanwhile, *comma* **in** my absence, did you receive an answer to your mail by one of my colleagues?

Recently, *comma* **in** my absence,

On Tuesday, *comma* **in** my absence,

etc.

OED:
B. adv.

1. During the time intervening between one particular period or event and another; while or until a particular event occurs; at the same time; for the present.

1877   J. A. Froude Short Stud. (1883) IV. i. x. 113   *The archbishop meanwhile had returned from his adventurous expedition.*